# Recreate WebApi code from .NET in .NET Core Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2019

I have this web API code in .NET framework that I want to recreate in .NET Core 3.1. As you can see I have 3 routes: Overview, GetMenu & SubMenu. I want to just implement those 3 in .NET Core 3.1 Visual Studio 2019. Kindly help.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [JWTAuthenticate]
    [CustomAttribute]
    [LogInfo]
    [LogException]
    [Route("Overview")]
    public string GetAccount()
    {
        return "Hello this is a sample api";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [JWTAuthenticate]
    [CustomAttribute]
    [LogInfo]
    [LogException]
    [Route("GetMenu")]
    public ResponseStatus GetMainMenuSubmenu()
    {
        ResponseStatus objResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        MenuResponseModel objMMSMModel = new MenuResponseModel();
        string allowedMenus = "";
        try
        {
            allowedMenus = CommonUtility.GetConfigValue("AllowedMenuIDs");
            MainMenuViewModel objMainMenuViewModel = LoginBizModel.GetMainMenuSubmenu(Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["emailID"]));
            if (objMainMenuViewModel != null && objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails != null && objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails.Count > 0)
            {
                objMMSMModel.CustomerName = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["CustomerName"]);
                objMMSMModel.UserName = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["userName"]);
                objMMSMModel.emailID = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["emailID"]);
                objMMSMModel.roleName = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["RoleName"]);

                objMMSMModel.MenuDetails = new List<MenuSubMenuModel>();

                //Expose menu(s) only that are given in webconfig
                objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails = objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails.Where(x => allowedMenus.Contains(x.MainMenuName)).ToList();
                foreach (MenuModel mm in objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails)
                {
                    MenuSubMenuModel menu = new MenuSubMenuModel();
                    menu.MainMenuName = mm.MainMenuName;
                    menu.SubMenuName = mm.SubMenuName;
                    menu.SubMenuId = mm.SubMenuId;
                    objMMSMModel.MenuDetails.Add(menu);
                }
            }

            objResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.SetResponseStatus(objResponseStatus, 0, 1000, Constants.Success, objMMSMModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.LogError(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex, new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber());
            ResponseStatus.SetExceptionResponseStatus(objResponseStatus, ex);
        }
        return objResponseStatus;
    }
```

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information for us to help. Please edit it with what code you're trying to convert, what you have tried, and what specific issue you are having. It would help if you could give us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JoeSewell can you help now?

Comment: I've retracted my close vote because the question now looks like it has enough information to be answerable, but I don't personally know the answer. Thanks for improving your question, it's more likely to get an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to convert the asp.net web api to asp.net core web api, you could refer to below steps:

1.`[HttpGet]`:asp.net core also contains `[HttpGet]`, there is no need to modify.

2.`[JWTAuthenticate]`: asp.net core has a new feature called schemem, if you want to use jwtAuthenticate, more details, you could refer to this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/).

3.`[CustomAttribute]` asp.net core also contains custom attribute, you could move the custom attribute to asp.net core.

4.`[LogInfo][LogException]`, if you want to use log in asp.net core, you should use DI to inject the loggder in the controller, and use it. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

5.`[Route("Overview")]`, asp.net core also contains routes, there is no need to modify it.

6. There is no change to this api method.

   public string GetAccount()
   {
   return "Hello this is a sample api";
   }

7.Asp.net core and asp.net are not contain ResponseStatus type in web api, it seems you have create a new response, you could install that Nugetpackage in asp.net core. For the code part, there is no change for the C#.

```
    public ResponseStatus GetMainMenuSubmenu()
    {
        ResponseStatus objResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        MenuResponseModel objMMSMModel = new MenuResponseModel();
        string allowedMenus = "";
        try
        {
            allowedMenus = CommonUtility.GetConfigValue("AllowedMenuIDs");
            MainMenuViewModel objMainMenuViewModel = LoginBizModel.GetMainMenuSubmenu(Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["emailID"]));
            if (objMainMenuViewModel != null && objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails != null && objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails.Count > 0)
            {
                objMMSMModel.CustomerName = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["CustomerName"]);
                objMMSMModel.UserName = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["userName"]);
                objMMSMModel.emailID = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["emailID"]);
                objMMSMModel.roleName = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["RoleName"]);

                objMMSMModel.MenuDetails = new List<MenuSubMenuModel>();

                //Expose menu(s) only that are given in webconfig
                objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails = objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails.Where(x => allowedMenus.Contains(x.MainMenuName)).ToList();
                foreach (MenuModel mm in objMainMenuViewModel.MainMenuDetails)
                {
                    MenuSubMenuModel menu = new MenuSubMenuModel();
                    menu.MainMenuName = mm.MainMenuName;
                    menu.SubMenuName = mm.SubMenuName;
                    menu.SubMenuId = mm.SubMenuId;
                    objMMSMModel.MenuDetails.Add(menu);
                }
            }

            objResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.SetResponseStatus(objResponseStatus, 0, 1000, Constants.Success, objMMSMModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.LogError(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex, new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber());
            ResponseStatus.SetExceptionResponseStatus(objResponseStatus, ex);
        }
        return objResponseStatus;
    }
```